# How Can I make configuration autofac's each module one by one

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

this code contain all autofac's models I don't want as such.I want to set one by one How can I make this

Asp.Net Core 3.1

```
          var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
          builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
          .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions()
          {
              Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
          }).SingleInstance();
```

AtuofacBusinessModule.cs

```
   public class AtuofacBusinessModule : Module
   {
       protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
       {
           builder.RegisterType<OrderService>().As<OrderService>();
           builder.RegisterType<AuthService>().As<AuthService>();
           builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<UserService>();


        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions()
           {
               Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
           }).SingleInstance();
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register it directly as what you want

```
 public class RegisterModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<StringService>().As<IStringService>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<IntService>().As<IIntService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<BoolService>().As<IBoolService>().InstancePerDependency();
        }
   }
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new RegisterModule());
        }
```